# How to solve an integration inside a function?

Tags: matlab

I defined a function in a separate m-file as follows:

```
function [f] =find_sol(l,y,z)

    global a b c d 

    % some equations..

    equation5= x^2+sin(x);
    f=int(equation5, 0, 3)
```

note that the equations are complicated (have to be integrated numerically), I just write a simple one for illustration
should I define x as a global variable???

Comment: Why not just define `syms x` at the top of the function?

Comment: I tried syms x but the computer hanged with no results